# How to add resource file to JAR in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14 and I want to add file outside of src to the JAR file. This is my current project structure.

I want to add layout.txt and saveddata.txt to the JAR file executable. I've been googling on that for a while can't find the solution

In case you need to see my code. This is how I am reading file

```
private Path layoutPath = Paths.get("resources/layout.txt");
content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(layoutPath));
```

Here is my project structure

[image: Layout Structure]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Create a folder called "resources" at the same level as "src"
2. Right click the folder, select "Mark Directory As -> Resources Root"

[image]

Comment: Still giving me NoSuchFileException. I marked it as Resource Root.

Comment: Presumably you mean your application is giving you an NSFE. Separate question if so, please post your code. General form is ```getClass().getResource("/path/image.png")```.

Comment: I have added the code. Can you check it again? Thanks :D

Comment: Try putting a "/" in front of the path and removing the folder "resources". The contents of your resources folder in the build is considered root, so your resource path would be ```"/layout.txt"```.

Comment: I have tried putting in root directory. It doesn't add to the JAR file also

Comment: If it's not in the JAR, you're going to get a NSFE no matter what the name, but it needs to be ```"/layout.txt"``` for the location you provided. You probably need to set up your Artifacts in Project Settings and be sure "Build on make" is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76322/discussion-between-renges-and-brian-topping).

Comment: from jetbrains;

"During the build process, by default, the resources are copied into the root of the compilation output folder. If necessary, you can specify a different folder within that output folder."

you need to follow this page for solution;

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-content-roots.html?origin=old_help

Answer (score 5):

- Make new directory with name as "resources" under your project root directory.
- Right click on that directory and select "Mark Directory As" ==>"Resources Root" option.

Comment: Still giving me NoSuchFileException after I have rebuilded

Comment: @Renges : The code is using a relative path, which makes it depend on the current working directory of the JVM that launches the tests. A more reliable way to read resource files is 'getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()', or, if necessary, 'getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()'. In a J2EE environment you'd typically use 'Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()'.

Comment: @Ranjeet, I think that `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` is the right way to go. May you please edit your answer and elaborate? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the `resources` directory was already marked as `Resources Root` but the content was missing in the `jar`. I had to manually add the `resources` dir to the `jar` artifact using the `Project Structure` window.

1. Open `Project Structures` window
2. Select `Artifacts` and click on the `+` button and then select `Directory Content`
3. Choose `resources` directory
4. Press `Apply` then `OK`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's still for me. I tried:

```
+ "Mark Directory As" ==>"Resources Root"
+ getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
+ getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()
and Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
```