# How to convert javafx with controller class to jar?

Tags: java, javafx, jar, controller

The project works perfectly fine in the IDE.
When I convert it to .jar it doesn't work anymore.

Because **only** the `Main2.java` class is converted to jar.

On my project, I have a controller class called `Controller2.java`

I want to convert the `Main2.java` + the `controlleur2.java` files together to a Jar file called `final.jar` for example! Because the application requires the controller to work.

How can I do that?

**Edit:**

When I run the jar file using cmd `java -jar fileName.jar` I get this error :

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
>   Source)

in the FXML file I have :

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller2">
```

and in `Main2.java` I have :

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Add new animal");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 426, 386));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? How did you create the JAR file? Keep in mind that you don't package the `*.java` files when creating an executable JAR file but rather the `*.class` files (from compiling the project).

Comment: I am using IntelliJ idea IDE. I created the jar file using the IDE: file-> project structure->add jar -> I choose the Main2 class then ok then I Build artifacts. There are class files created in the production folder: https://i.imgur.com/XtnpyaR.png

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you use the java -jar command in a command prompt window?

Comment: I used  the Ide to convert to jar , and I double click on  the jar file to run it ! I didnt use any command

Comment: Run it from the command line and see if it produces any errors

Comment: I Did and I get this error : ` Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source) at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source) `

Comment: That is most likely not the full stack trace (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)). My guess is you're getting a "Location is required" error. That means the FXML file could not be located where you said it should be. If it works in the IDE but not the JAR file then, since you're using `getResource`, that typically means the FXML is not being included in the JAR file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887524/how-to-add-resource-file-to-jar-in-intellij

Answer (score 0):

Steps to covert to jar.

1. Click on edit configuration on top right corner of intellij
   [Add module dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/634ZG.png)
2. Then click on modify options-> Add VM Options then add following module path.

   --module-path
   ""
   --add-modules
   javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
3. Click on File -> Project structure.  Then click on Artifacts. Add new artifact by clicking "+" -> Jar -> from modules and dependencies.
4. Then click on Main class to select the main class.
5. Then click on "+" icon and select file. Navigate to openjfx\bin and add all the dll files to the project. click on OK
   [Plus icon to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoTX0.png)
6. Go to Build -> Build Artifacts -> Rebuid.
7. Navaigate to build\artifacts<name> u will find the jar built